# Upgrade to 7 Error: Could not load type 'Umbraco.Web.UI.Install.Default'

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco6, umbraco5, umbraco-contour

Been trying to upgrade to V7 from V6 for a few days now, running in to a lot of problems.

The first time I tried to do it, I actually did upgrade, but then an issue with UComponents made me roll back, I removed Ucompenets and tried to upgrade again (using Nuget)

When I run the site it tries to take me to the installation wizard (http://mydomain.local/install/) but I get this error:

```
 Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Umbraco.Web.UI.Install.Default'.

 <%@ Page Language="c#" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="Umbraco.Web.UI.Install.Default" EnableViewState="False" %>
```

I didn't have this issue the first time I tried, thinking something is still hanging around from the first attempt.

I have seen this error on the forums but with no solutions :-(

Any ideas?

Comment: uComponents is not compatible with v7 and so should be removed anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix it.

Solution!

I deleted the /install folder... and its works!

Another quirk that needs to be added to the documentation!

Comment: I think that there is no need for the install folder to exist anymore in the latest v7 as I believe they have an MVC route for it. The fact you had the folder still there will likely have caused the installer some confusion. Glad you got it sorted though, perhaps give something back by adding this to the documentation ;)

Comment: I saw this in the documentation for [7.2](http://our.umbraco.org/contribute/releases/720/) "Please also remove the /Install folder if you haven't done so, it is no longer used and might conflict with the new upgrader if it's still there."